# How to select refresh rate of all materialized views in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to select every refresh rate of my materialized views in Oracle.
By refresh rate i mean SYSDATE + 1/24 (what u get from the column info in the schema browser)

When I execute

```
select * from all_mviews;
```

it shows me the last refresh date but not the refresh rate.

For the record I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: You'll have to explain what do you understand under the *refresh rate*. If you mean the ratio of the *refresh count of a particular MV divided by the total number of the MV refresh* I'm afraid that such *history* data is not available.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Materialized views (and materialized view refresh groups) are (assuming they are refreshed on a schedule) refreshed by a job (`dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` depending on the Oracle version).  That job has a schedule that you can query if that's what you're looking for.  Assuming a recent `dbms_scheduler` job, you'll have some history of when the refresh job ran previously if that's what you're after.

Comment: By refresh rate i mean the number of time the MV is refreshed such as => SYSDATE + 1/24, So I would like to see that refresh rate for each of my MV in a table.  And about the version i'm using 'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary view `USER_REFRESH` gives you the information about the next refresh.

Example MV (without a refresh group)

```
create materialized view mv_18 
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH SYSDATE 
  NEXT  SYSDATE + 3/24
as
select * from dual;
```

gives this result - see column `INTERVAL`

```
select ROWNER, RNAME, NEXT_DATE, INTERVAL
from USER_REFRESH;

ROWNER                         RNAME                          NEXT_DATE           INTERVAL                                                                                                                                                                                                
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------- ---------------
xxx                            MV_18                          06.10.2021 21:21:52 SYSDATE + 3/24
```

If you use a *refresh group* it is better to look at the view `USER_REFRESH_CHILDREN`, because the `RNAME` is the *refresh group* name

```
select RNAME,INTERVAL,JOB  
from USER_REFRESH_CHILDREN
where name = 'MV_18A'; -- = mview_name
```

The column `JOB` (if not zero) points in `USER_JOBS` to the job that refreshs the MV.

Starting with 18g the view got a new column `JOB_NAME` which references the view `user_scheduler_jobs` for the job that is responsible for the refresh.

My observation is that starting with 19g only `dbms_scheduler` jobs are used for the refresh.

```
select RNAME,INTERVAL,JOB,JOB_NAME 
from USER_REFRESH_CHILDREN
where name = 'MV_18A'; -- = mview_name
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much